# @PostConstruct method in a managed bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

using this type of code lines in `@PostConstruct` method :

```
listA = myService.getMylist();
```

so If we are using this in a `@PostConstruct` method in a managed bean (JEE application) what would you give me as an advice:

- Using a try catch block.
- Don't use this type of code lines in a `@PostConstruct` method.

Because when I'm testing my application my database is full, but when I will deliver it the db must be empty and the administrator who will update de DB . so there will be some exceptions of course.

Comment: Why would an empty db throw an error?

Comment: Just make sure `myService` is right instantiated/injected before used and `MyService#getMylist` method always return a `List<Whatever>` even if there's no data in your data source.

Comment: thank you , but every thing that you said is right , but if listA is null , using it will throw an error ?

Comment: What part of *always return a `List<Whatever>` even if there's no data in your data source* didn't you understand? =\

Comment: I didn't like your comment :) but thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your setup really. Either is appropriate, as long as any exceptions are handled. That could simply be iterate over the List for each item, and if no items (or is null) then do nothing with the object. If it is an actual error state for no items to return (ie the page cannot function without that item), then throw an exception.

Perhaps it would be better to throw the exception in the code that gets data from the database though (such as in a service method, rather than a DAO, or whatever equivalent code you have)? That way you are removing functionality from the managed bean and can handle it within your framework. Or as is more appropriate with List collections, just make sure you instantiate it before you return it. (ie `List<Object> listA = new ArrayList<Object>; ...*populate list* .... return listA;`) Then when you iterate, nothing will be called.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, the best practice is to initialize an empty collection if there are no elements instead of just reference pointing it to null. So if you are designing the service layer then do not return null collections - instead return empty collection. Also if this is a per-requisite of your design that the list must not be empty ( which means it is an unacceptable condition) the you must throw an error to indicate invalid condition and stop the initialization of the bean.